# Can every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ a measurable set (with respect to some measure $\mu$)?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A problem occur to me when I was learning real analysis:

> Can we construct a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $E\subset\mathbb{R}$, $E$ is $\mu$-measurable?

I know that for Lebesgue measure, this is not true. There are many non-measureable sets (with respect to Lebesgue measure) on $\mathbb{R}$. However, I wonder whether we can construct a measure $\mu$ such that there are no $\mu$-nonmeasurable sets.

I was thinking about adding non-measurable sets directly into $m$, i.e., define $\mu(E)=m(E)$ if $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\mu(E)=0$ if $E$ is not Lebesgue measurable. However, I was not sure that $\mu$ is still a measure after such modification.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I don’t think there are any measures that are not absolutely continuous wrt counting measure given that the latter is zero only an the empty set.

Comment: If $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ that is not atomic, then there is a Cantor set $E$ with $\mu(E) > 0$.  So if $B$ is a Bernstein set, then $B$ is not $\mu$-measurable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set

Comment: No, this is the problem of measure, and, in a sense, Lebesgue measure is the 'best' you can do to include as many subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as possible and include the Borel sets.